# Quicksort algorithm using percentiles

Tags: algorithm, quicksort

I was reading on Wikipedia about Quicksort using percentiles [Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Using_percentiles) and I didn't understand why when we do a 25-75 split the running time will be O(n log n)? I tried to develop the recursion tree and I didn't have any result.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming larger partition is always 75%, then number of recursions is log1/.75 = log1.5. In best case, larger partition is always 50% and number of recursions is log1/.5 = log2. Since time complexity ignores constant factors, both cases are considered to be O(n log(n)).

Comment: So as I have understood, when splitting 25 and 75% I ignore the 25% part i of the recursion tree?

Comment: @tonyjk - correct, the focus is on the maximum number of recursions, and even though the 25% corresponds to n log4(n) and 75% corresponds to n log1.5(n), both are O(n log(n)). You could use two recursion trees, one for 25%, one for 75%.